# My javascript function won't pause my video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I had this working before and for some reason the script no longer works. I've been spending ages trying to solve it but can't seem to find the reason. I just want my video to pause upon clicking.

```
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

function myFunction() {
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
    btn.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    video.pause();
    btn.innerHTML = "Play";
  }
}
```

And here is the HTML  code:

```
    <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

  <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Pause</button>
```

Comment: This should `pause` or `play` video. there is no problem with code AFAIT. can you check what is the error in console.

Comment: Mention the Errors in console

Comment: Error code says:

4script.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'paused')
    at myFunction (script.js:6:13)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:96:51)